# Bug sources in programming

Tags: nullpointerexception, indexoutofboundsexception, integer-overflow

- de-referencing a null pointer
- comparison floats with equals
- integer overflow
- array index out of bound

What else popular mistakes in programming do you know?

Comment: what language (family of languages)? Few errors never occur in some languages

Comment: in all languages

Comment: @JacekCz in which languages never occur?